# Random number assignment to a list value

Tags: python, random

I need to assign a random number to each value of a list of str. The number must be between 1 and len(list). I can't figure out how to make the numbers not to repeat.

I managed to assign a number to each value but I can't get the numbers to be unique and not repeat themselves.[This is what I've got so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF6NK.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post your code in a picture. Format it as code into the question.

Comment: The usual way to get a random list of non-repeating values is to start with a *non*-random list of values (from `list(range(...))`, perhaps), and call `random.shuffle()` on it.

Comment: And once you have the list of non-repeating values, you can pair them up with the names to create the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

mylist = ["cat", "dog", "rabbit", "fish"]

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    mylist[i] = (mylist[i], random.randint(1,10))

    print(mylist)
```